# Restore array items after every iteration in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-validation

I am trying to restore all array items after each for loop iteration. This I need to set Laravel validation `Rule::notIn($arry)`

I have an array of `station_id` generated by cloned input fields. I want to check if all cloned station ids are unique, and so be sure that no repeated station in the metro route.

For cloned fields, I am setting up a rule using for a loop by counting cloned items.

So the issue is, I want to use `Rule::notIn($stationIds) except the current iteration item id so I can validate by checking the current id is not in the rest of the array items.

```
public function rules()
{
    
    // getting all input fields value
    $rStationIds = $this->get('station_id')
    ...

    // get the max number of input
    $counter = $this->getMaxCount($rStationIds, ...);
    $rules = [];

    // loop through each item
    for ($r = 0; $r < $counter; $r++) {
              
        unset($rStationIds[$r]);

        $rules['station_id'][$r] = ['required', 'int', Rule::notIn($rStationIds)];
    }

    ...
}
```

The problem in the above code is that when I `unset($var)` the current item, it never reset back with the original array elements; thus, the last field will have nothing to compare because the array will get empty.

I am okay with any other approach as well to check the unique item for the cloned station id fields.

Comment: How about:
0. new temp var with the value of the current element
1. unset the current element
2. notIn(array)
3. array[] = new temp var
See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your loop to:

```
// loop through each item
for ($r = 0; $r < $counter; $r++) {
    $temp = $rStationIds[$r];

    unset($rStationIds[$r]);

    $rules['station_id'][$r] = ['required', 'int', Rule::notIn($rStationIds)];

    $rStationIds[$r] = $temp;
}
```

Comment: There might be a better solution, but this is simplest I came out with.

Comment: Thank you. This solution can fix my problem as I need all elements back in the array on every interaction. However, I would like to know if there is any way to restore entire array with the original indexes. Thanks for your help.